# Is there a pandas function that will allow me to compare duplicates based on timestamp?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have approx 300k records and am looking for duplicates.  I have written a simple script to do this and it works well:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("input.csv")
dupes = df.duplicated(subset=['Forename','Surname', 'Day of Birth', 'Month of Birth', 'Year of Birth'])
df['Duplicate'] = dupes
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

However, there is another column in the original data, a timestamp, and I've been asked to only flag duplicates where the timestamps are within 1hr of each other.

I guess I could just use a for loop and go through it, finding each marked as a duplicate by the script above, then finding every other instance of the same value, then calculating if the timestamp is within 1hr, and adding a new column with the result. But this is going to be very slow (in some instances there are 10+ duplicates of the same value which all need to be compared to each other), and I wondered if anyone has a more efficient method? I will have more files like this and am new to pandas so hoping to learn from you all.

Thanks

I haven't tried in pandas yet

Answer (score 0):

You can use `diff` on `timestamps` and then use `.dt.components['hours']` to create another condition for hours:

```
hour_condition = df['timestamps'].diff().dt.components['hours'].le(1)
hour_dupes =  df.loc[dupes & hour_condition]
```

Comment: in my opinion you can create a new hour column and include it in the subset list , `['Forename','Surname', 'Hour of Birth','Day of Birth', 'Month of Birth', 'Year of Birth']`

Comment: Thanks for responding @lackti Sorry, not sure I follow.  Is this for the output? There's no need for "Hour of Birth", the calculation I need is to check whether the Timestamp for two duplicates is within 1 hour.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I got TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Yes, I mean you need to create a new column, that indicates the hour of the day, and then select the duplicates by (year,month,day,hour) like that you can catch the duplicated rows by hour , I hope you understand what I mean!

Comment: I don't think that will be sufficient.  Within 1hr could be a different value for hour (22:59 / 23:14 etc)

Comment: Aha I got what you mean, I think you need to use a unsupervised ML algorithm like K-means to easily solve this problem, I'm not sure which algorithm to use, but just search about it , it's not difficult stuff I'm pretty sure, Just I don't have much time to search about it.